# Optimizing SphereInFrustrum check

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, opengl

I have this SphereInFrustrum function here:

```
0.49%  int FrustumG::sphereInFrustum(Vec3 &p, float radius) {

        int result = INSIDE;
        float distance;

2.40%   for(int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
7.94%       distance = pl[i].distance(p);
12.21%      if (distance < -radius)
0.67%           return OUTSIDE;
3.67%       else if (distance < radius)
                result =  INTERSECT;
        }
        return(result);

       }
```

The numbers are from my code profiler. The issue is that, this check is taking longer than actually rendering. The whole point of implementing geometry culling was so that I could have really big levels. I really just need a very quick and dirty way to see if an AABB is in or out. Right now I provide it with the radius of the cube and the center. Given that my boxes are AABB, is there a faster way to do this? I favor speed over accuracy.

Thanks

If I provided the cube's min and max would that make it faster? I'm sure there must be a way to do this without the distance formula with an expensif square root;

```
float Plane::distance(Vec3 &p) {

    return (d + normal.innerProduct(p));
}


float Vec3::innerProduct(Vec3 &v) {

    return (x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the frustum impelemntation given here: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/viewfrustum/index.php?gimp .  Is that right?

Comment: It's hard to believe that a simple float comparison is really taking 12.21% of your execution time.  If so, then your distance function must be *damn* fast (as in negative clock cycles fast).  Maybe the profiler is attributing part of your distance function's execution to the `if` test here.  Can you post the code for `distance`?  I imagine that more opportunities for optimization would exist there.

Comment: Yes that is correct, it works great and all but when I get massive ammounts of objects, the checks outweigh the rendering time

Comment: Where do you see a square root?

Comment: Ooops I thought it was a distance function not a dot product

Comment: Small improvement: use float minusdistance = -distance; -- maybe also done by the optimizer.

Comment: Do you use the volatile keyword for some members?

Comment: All these methods are const! Use the const keyword!

Comment: try reordering the tests, making the most probable results the first ones: if (distance >= radius) {;} else if (distance < -radius) { return outside; } else { result = intersect; } -- but I think your performance problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Make sure `distance` and `innerProduct` are both inline.

Comment: @Milo: I understand that you have a lot of objects and that this code is being called many times.  That doesn't change the fact that a simple floating-point comparison cannot possibly take more time than a function call that computes the normalized distance of a point from a plane.  Something is screwy with your profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to just leave a comment to ask a question but i only seem to be able to leave an answer, this is just an observation:

Does this code really do what you want to do?

```
        int result = INSIDE;
        float distance;

2.40%   for(int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
7.94%       distance = pl[i].distance(p);
12.21%      if (distance < -radius)
0.67%           return OUTSIDE;
3.67%       else if (distance < radius)
                result =  INTERSECT;
```

how this function reads to me is, assume the sphere is inside, for each point on your frustrum i, take the distance between i and the center of sphere p, if this distance is less than negative radius... and here my paradigm is destroyed.

So this returns early if you have a negative distance that is less than your negative radius?  Is that really what you want right there?

Comment: all I need to know is if its in or out, I dont care how it gets done,

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say those were planes, not points, and that the distance is normalized.  Points on the side of the plane facing the inside of the frustum are positive, whereas points on the side of the plane facing the outside of the frustum are negative.  So if the sphere's center is -40 from the plane, and the sphere's radius is 30, then since -40 < -30, it is completely outside the frustum.

Comment: @P Daddy: That makes much more sense than what i had in mind.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really executing this code for each sphere ? If you do, no wonder it's slower.

You should use a hierarchical approach, which can cull entire parts of the scenes in one call. For instance, you can use a quadtree of spheres.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas (in order of increasing complexity)

1. **Elimintate branches** - it may be faster (depending on platform and compiler) to compute all 6 distances and return based on the minimum of them. E.g. on PowerPC, `minDist = (d < minDist) ? d : minDist` can be computed with an `fsel` instruction and avoid the branches.
2. **Unroll (part I)** - Unrolling the loop for all six planes might give the compiler better chances to optimize the code (by hiding instruction latency).
3. **Unroll (part II)** - Can you process multiple spheres at once? Again, you might be able to hide some of the latency.
4. **SIMD** - If you don't mind getting your hands dirty with SIMD, you can store the "transpose" of 3 planes together in 4 quads. This lets you compute the dot products more easily, without having to do "horizontal" SIMD operations. Symbolically, this would look like

---

```
vec4 sphereX = sphere.splat(0);
vec4 sphereY = sphere.splat(1);
vec4 sphereZ = sphere.splat(2);

vec4 dot = sphereX * planesX; // planesX is the x components of 3 planes
dot += sphereY * planesY; 
dot += sphereZ * planesZ;
dot += planesDistance;
// dot now contains the results of 3 distances
// now do the same for the other 3 planes
```

---

The actual SIMD code will depend on the platform and compiler.

There are also some methods for doing frustum queries on kd-trees (i.e. [MLRTA](http://lukasz.dk/files/mlrta.pdf)) - I've never tried them, but it should cut down dramatically on the number of spheres you need to query.

Hope that helps, let me know if anything is unclear.